# Drupal: Different output for first item in a block

Tags: drupal

I have a Block created by a View that outputs the 5 latest posts in the sidebar. For each of those nodes, the Block contains the title of the post and the posted date.

Just for the first of those posts I'd like to display more information: taxonomy terms, author name and comment count.

In my View I can send all those fields to the Block, but now I'm wondering: How can I make those fields display JUST for the first post?

The .tpl file that displays this content gets called in a loop, so in there I'm not able to put a counter that tracks whether we're at the first post or post 2 - 5.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what Views attachments are for. Create an attachment display type with the extra fields and a limit of 1, and attach it to the main view. Give the main view an offset of 1 and you should be all set...